# Yii2 external data retrieving difficulties

Tags: php, yii2

let me explain my problem, hope you get an idea of what it is.

I have a web service which hide from public access, and have designed a secure way of mysql sql querying using to the service across the websites. so i dont think i can really use the current model layer of Yii2, and that also means i hardly can use `activeDataProvider` as no database present.

Currently what i do is to write raw sqls and get all the results and then feed into dataprovider using `ArrayDataProvider`.

e.g.

```
$sql="select * from a_table";
$result=$remote->select($sql);

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $result,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['date', 'name'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);

return $this->render('index', [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

that pose a problem, everytime i need to query the full table. This is not idea if the table is very large. It is better to query in the size of 10 something, however if i do

```
$sql="select * from a_table LIMIT 10";
```

no pagination will appear in my case...How do i solve this problem? And if this is not an idea way to talk to external data services, what is ur suggestion?

Comment: Well, you're page size is 10, and your result is 10 too. So pagination won't have any role.

Comment: No, my result is more than 10, 10results just for testing

Answer (score 0):

The pagination won't appear because you only feed 10 rows to the ArrayDataProvider and it has no way of knowing there is more.

If you want to use `DataProvider` with remote fetching I would advise you to create your own `MyRemoteDataProvider` class by extending `BaseDataProvider` and overriding at least these four methods:

```
use yii\data\BaseDataProvider;

class MyRemoteDataProvider extends BaseDataProvider
{
    protected function prepareModels()
    {
    }

    protected function prepareKeys($models)
    {
    }

    protected function prepareTotalCount()
    { 
    }

    protected function sortModels($models, $sort)
    {
    }
}
```

.. and then of course use your `MyRemoteDataProvider` instead of `ArrayDataProvider`. If you don't know what the methods should return, please read documentation for [BaseDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html) or get inspired by [ArrayDataProvider](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ArrayDataProvider.php) implementation.